# how to start drawing a line with a space between y-axis and it using d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm drawing a simple line chart with axes.

```
// Set the scales
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(data.map(function(d) {
        return d.labels;}))
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.values; })])
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

// draw line graph
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.labels); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.values); })
    .interpolate("linear");

// Create the SVG 'canvas'
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("class", "chart")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom).append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.right + ")");

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

svg.append("path")
  .attr("d",line(data))
  .attr("stroke", color)
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .attr("fill", "none");
```

Here you can see that it works, but the line starts from the y-axis so that the values don't correspond to the labels: http://jsfiddle.net/5r63j/12/
It may be fixed by replacing the `.rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0);` by `.rangePoints([0, width], 0);`, so that the values correspond to the labels and it's quite good, but there is no padding between the y-axis and the line.

Is it possible to move the start point of the line itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close but not quite! :)

Instead of:

```
.rangePoints([0, width], 0);
```

you just use

```
.rangePoints([0, width], 0.5);
```

And you will get this:

[image]

[Here is jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qasgy/).

Documentation for second parameter of rangePoints() is [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#ordinal_rangeBands). Illustration for parameter meaning:

[image]

Comment: I need same. But it does not work with time scale. I tried `xScale = d3.time.scale.utc().range([0, chartWidth], 0.5)` Any solution for this ?

Comment: @murli2308 I think you should post another question for this. It is an interesting one anyway.

Comment: 33 I already added it and got an answer too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614868/add-space-between-x-axis-and-line-with-time-scale