# Using D3js v4 how to add space between y axis and line in line chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How do I add space between the lines drawn and the y-axis using version 4 of d3.js .
Below is my code.

```
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]).nice();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/oVrz04HU9jXuNxADhW5P?p=preview) a simillar question had already been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34619240/7473025

The only miniscule change i made was:

```
var minDate = d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.date.getTime(); }),
    maxDate = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.date.getTime(); }),
    padding = (maxDate - minDate) * .05;

x.domain([minDate - padding, maxDate + padding]);
```

Comment: No. That moves whole x-axis away from y-axis

Comment: Yes naturally, if you don't move the x-axis along with the line then the data shown will be inaccurate, it's a bit difficult to know what effect you are trying to acheive when you haven't posted a working example.

Comment: Updated my answer